# .htaccess redirect creates infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess

Trying to create a .htaccess redirect results in an infinite loop. This is what my code currently looks like:

`Redirect / http://www.website.com/new/`

Any idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by creating an index page and redirecting from there.

`Redirect /index.html http://website.com/new/`

Answer (score 0):

try `Redirect 301 / http://www.website.com/new/`

Comment: Solved it by creating an index page and redirecting from there. `Redirect /index.html http://website.com/new/`